# In beamer, how can you use \tableofcontents[hidesubsections] and still render correctly the TOC?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

Using: pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)

When using the `\tableofcontents` in `beamer`, using the theme `Berkeley`, with the option `[hidesubsections]`, `[hideothersubsections]` and the options to hide subsections, it renders the TOC wrongly. It introduces too much space to separate the section names.

The aim is to have a slide before each beginning of a section, with the ToC highlighting the current section and showing its subsections.

Given the following Minimal not Working Example(MnWE):

```
    \documentclass[]{beamer}

    \usetheme{Berkeley}

    \begin{document}

    \AtBeginSection[]{
    \frame{
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
    }
    }

    \begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[hidesubsections]
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[currenthideallsubsections]
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

    \section{section 1}
    \subsection{subsection1}
    \begin{frame}
    subsection1
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{subsection2}
    \begin{frame}
    subsection1
    \end{frame}

    \section{section 2}
    \subsection{subsection1}
    \begin{frame}
    subsection1
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{subsection2}
    \begin{frame}
    subsection1
    \end{frame}

    \section{section 3}hidesubsections
    \begin{frame}
    subsection1
    \end{frame}
    \section{section 4}
    \begin{frame}
    subsection1
    \end{frame}
    \section{section 5}
    \begin{frame}
    subsection1
    \end{frame}
    \section{section 6}
    \begin{frame}
    subsection1
    \end{frame}
    \section{section 7}
    \begin{frame}
    subsection1
    \end{frame}
    \section{section 8}
    \begin{frame}
    subsection1
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

It will show the following images for the first, and third slide. The second is the same as the first:

The TOC with hidesubsections option and displayed wrongly, too many space to separate section names:
[image: The TOC with hidesubsections option and too many space to separate section names]

The TOC without hidesubsections option, displayed correctly:
[image: The TOC without hidesubsections option, displayed correctly.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the updated answer:

The internal command \beamer@sectionintoc (defined in the file beamerbasetoc.sty) controls how the section entries will be typeset in the ToC; it issues a \vskip1.5em that adds vertical spacing between section entries. With the help of the etoolbox package you can easily patch the command to add less vertical spacing.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}{\vskip1.5em}{\vskip0.5em}{}{}
\makeatother

\title[Short Title]{My very long title that doesn't fix into the footer}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection, hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\clearpage

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}


\section{Intro}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Welcome}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 1}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 2}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Red}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Red}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Green}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Green}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Blue}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Blue}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 3}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 3}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 4}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 4}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 5}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 5}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 6}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 6}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 7}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 7}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 8}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 8}
...
\end{frame}

\section{The end}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The end}
End of file :-)
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I think this should probably be the right answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not said. I want to have a slide showing the toc with only the subsections of the current section before begins any section. I am adapting the question to express this correctly.

Comment: I have edited my answer . Have a look

Comment: Thank you, the pause options is awesome.

But if you increase enough the number of sections, up to eight. It has the same problem. It puts too much space to spare section names, and the section 7, and 8, are too low, not visible. It renders it wrongly since it has the hidesubsections and similar activated.

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer